# Generalized intermediate value theorem for $s f(x) -t f(y) = (s - t) f(z)$

Tags: calculus

As we know for $s, t >0,$ we have
$s f(x) + t f(y) = (s + t) f(z)$, for continues function $f$ on $[a, b]$ ($x, y\in (a, b)$).
Is it true for $s f(x) - t f(y) = (s - t) f(z)$ ????

Comment: What is for $sf(x)−tf(y)=?$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Consider $f(x)=x$, $s=1,t=1,x=0,y=1$. Then $sx-ty=-1$, which is never equal to $(s-t)f(z) = 0$ for all $z$